# How to programmatically send sequential TXs quickly

Tags: transactions

I'm trying to send several TXs as rapidly as possible. Doing so without waiting for a transaction receipt, and not specifying a nonce, results in a nonce error (because it will try to send a TX with the same nonce as the previous attempt).

So it seems like there are two options:

- Await the transaction receipt before another TX can be sent (but then it would take on average 17 seconds between TXs, right?)
- Set the nonce for each TX, which should allow sending these TXs out as quickly as possible (they won't be picked up any quicker of course, I'm talking about sending speed, as in how long it takes to get them recognized on the network).

Are there any potential drawbacks of the nonce approach? And are there any other ways to send TXs quickly?